# What's a doent?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, terminology

In some software forums, posts refer to something called a "doent" (e.g., [here](http://www.justskins.com/forums/remove-all-paragraph-and-90912.html) and [here](http://www.justskins.com/forums/because-it-is-not-56434.html)).

> When trying to open .tif files in Photoshop 6.0, I get the following error message, "Could not open...because it is not the right kind of **doent**."
>
> Does InDesign CS have a quick way to remove all paragraph and character style overrides throughout a **doent**?

I have no idea what a *doent* is, and simple searches on Google and the Adobe documentation don't reveal any answers.

What's a *doent*?

Answer (score 9):

Probably an automated typo for "document", a result of a strong filter for removing certain words.

Comment: I support this idea. If you take a look in the html you will find e.g. http://www.justskins.com/forums/doent-security-has-been-66038.html which will not be resolved, after changing to http://www.justskins.com/forums/document-security-has-been-66038.html it will open.

Comment: Yet another good example of why indiscriminately brute-censoring strings of text is a bad, bad idea.

Comment: AKA The Scunthorpe Problem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Comment: This was a fun censorship. Much more fun than the one used by some sites that cut off a simple and kind word like "hi"...